# invalid value from generic function ‘dbListFields’, class “numeric”, expected “character”

Tags: mysql, r

I am trying to read table from a database and getting error:
**Error in .valueClassTest(ans, "character", "dbListFields") : 
  invalid value from generic function ‘dbListFields’, class “numeric”, expected “character”**

Here is my code:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(dbConnect)
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='user',
             password='pwd', dbname='blank_copy',
             host='IPaddress', port=portnumber)
dbListTables(mydb)
dbListFields(mydb, 'SELECT * FROM tablename')
```

I don't know why am getting such an error of class for this particular table.

Can anyone help me on this error?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a table name as the second argument for `dbListFields`, per the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.5-1/topics/dbListFields).

So you should do something like this:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(dbConnect)
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='user',
         password='pwd', dbname='blank_copy',
         host='IPaddress', port=portnumber)
tables <- dbListTables(mydb)
#tables is a character vector, so you can just pass a subset of that
fields <- dbListFields(mydb, tables[1])
```

Comment: Thank you Randall.